# How to get "jvisualvm Threads Inspector" working?

Tags: java, jvisualvm

jvisualvm 1.8.0_60
Threads Inspector 1.0.1
is installed and Active
but when I open a .hprof file there are no stacks in the "Threads at the heap dump" section of the summary tab, just a list of thread names. Nothing reported on out or err.

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jvisualvm --modules --list | grep -i thread
com.sun.tools.visualvm.threaddump                 1.0     Enabled  
com.sun.tools.visualvm.modules.threadinspect      1.0.1   Enabled
```

I'm sure this used to work in jdk1.7, but I need it working in jdk1.8.

I tried "eclipse Memory Analyzer" but it errored out with

```
An internal error occurred during: "Parsing heap dump from 'fail.hprof'".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

the file was obtained with

```
jmap -F -dump:format=b,file=fail.hprof 1234
```

Anyone able to reproduce this issue or know of a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Threads Inspector" will only work without the -F flag.
In fact most snapshot inspectors won't work at all with the -F flag;

- yourkit
- jprofiler
- eclipse Memory Analyzer

Some will partially work;

- jhat
- jvisualvm